# Make text inside column not going over another column

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I would like to be able to make that the text inside a column, when too long, does not go over another column.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row vdivide">
  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <span id="asd" class="text-truncate">askdl kansld knalskdn laknd laksm dlams dlkams lmdak sdmlaksmd la
                        askld malsk mdalsk mldaksml dkasm ldkamsl dkamsl kdmalskmd alsm dlakm skdlams kdm
                        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-divider"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-lighter">Sesso:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="sesso"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Data di nascita:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="dataNascita"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Regione:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="regione"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Città:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="citta"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Anzianità di lavoro:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="anzianita"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Disponibilità online:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="coachingOnline"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Email:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="email"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Cellulare:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="cellulare"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

This is the code i used and an image that demostrate the result.
I would like to have something like:

askdl kansld knalskdn laknd
laksm dlams dlkams lmdak sdmlaksmd
la askld malsk mdalsk mldaksml dkasm
ldkamsl dkamsl kdmalskmd alsm dlakm
skdlams kdm

But I don't know how to achieve something like this. Any tips?

Comment: Are you trying to wrap or truncate the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the `white-space : nowrap` from your bootstrap class `text-truncate` forcing the span element "`#asd`" to push your paragraph into one line

> nowrap
>       Collapses white space as for normal, but suppresses line breaks (text wrapping) within the source.

you can fix this by doing this :

```
#asd {
  white-space : normal !important;
 }
```

check now :

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row vdivide">
  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <span id="asd" style="white-space : normal" class="text-truncate">askdl kansld knalskdn laknd laksm dlams dlkams lmdak sdmlaksmd la
         askld malsk mdalsk mldaksml dkasm ldkamsl dkamsl kdmalskmd alsm dlakm skdlams kdm
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-divider"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-lighter">Sesso:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="sesso"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Data di nascita:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="dataNascita"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Regione:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="regione"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Città:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="citta"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Anzianità di lavoro:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="anzianita"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Disponibilità online:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="coachingOnline"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Email:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="email"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Cellulare:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="cellulare"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can break your line in `span` by using `display:block`. Remove `class="text-truncate"`

```css
.asd{
display:block
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row vdivide">
  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <span class="asd">askdl kansld knalskdn </span>
      <span class="asd">laknd laksm dlams dlkams lmdak sdmlaksmd la
                        </span>
      <span class="asd"> askld malsk mdalsk mldaksml dkasm ldkamsl  </span>
      <span class="asd"> dkamsl kdmalskmd alsm dlakm skdlams kdm
                        </span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="vertical-divider"></div>
  <div class="col-lg-6 text-center">
    <div class="mt-5">
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-lighter">Sesso:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="sesso"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Data di nascita:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="dataNascita"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Regione:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="regione"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Città:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="citta"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Anzianità di lavoro:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="anzianita"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Disponibilità online:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="coachingOnline"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Email:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="email"></span>
      </p>
      <p class="border-bottom">
        <span class="font-weight-normal">Cellulare:</span>
        <span class="font-weight-lighter" id="cellulare"></span>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```